# Get a mini browser window with no toolbars (only page display area)

Tags: python, browser, toolbar

With chrome-driver I can get side some stuff, such as like this:

`options.add_argument('--content-shell-hide-toolbar')
options.add_argument('--top-controls-hide-threshold')`

but I would like to have a naked window, with anything but the display area.

any hints of approach? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

With pyqt5, this is doable, for example:

https://github.com/learnpyqt/15-minute-apps/blob/master/browser/browser.py

on Mac, these dependencies have to be get on terminal:

`$ sudo pip3 install pyqt5
$ sudo pip3 install pyqtwebengine`